# Why ROUGE score results are confusing for non-English Languages?

Tags: non-english, rouge

**Case 1:**

```
t1='match is needed'
t2='match is perfect'
scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1'], use_stemmer=True)
scores = scorer.score(t1,t2)
print(scores)
```

O/P:

> {'rouge1': Score(precision=0.6666666666666666, recall=0.6666666666666666, fmeasure=0.6666666666666666)}

**This is working.**

**Case 2:**

```
t1='नवी दिल्ली: जगभरातील उद्योजक, सत्ताधीशांच्या काळ्या पैशासंदर्भातील उघड झालेला गोपनीय दस्ताऐवज ‘पनामा पेपर्स‘मुळे खळबळ माजलेली असताना, परदेशात मालमत्ता लपवणाऱ्या भारतीयांना ही कृती महागात पडू शकते असा कडक इशारा केंद्रीय अर्थमंत्री अरुण जेटली यांनी दिला आहे. काळ्या पैशाच्या समस्येवरील उपाययोजनेअंतर्गत गेल्या वर्षी (2015) कराश्रय सुविधा देणाऱ्या देशांमध्ये अघोषित मालमत्ता असलेल्यांना माहिती सरकारकडे उघड करण्याचा आदेश देण्यात आला होता. त्यावेळी 4,147 कोटी रुपयांच्या मालमत्ता घोषित करण्यात आली होती. भारतासह सुमारे 500 उद्योजक, सत्ताधीश आणि '
t2='नवी दिल्ली: जगभरातील उद्योजक, सत्ताधीशांच्या काळ्या पैशासंदर्भातील उघड झालेला गोपनीय दस्ताऐवज ‘पनामा पेपर्स‘मुळे खळबळ माजलेली असताना, परदेशात मालमत्ता लपवणाऱ्या भारतीयांना ही कृती महागात पडू शकते असा कडक इशारा केंद्रीय अर्थमंत्री अरुण जेटली यांनी दिला आहे. तरीही परदेशात मालमत्ता लपवून धोका पत्करणाऱ्यांना हा खेळ अत्यंत महागात पडू शकतो. काळ्या पैशाच्या समस्येवरील उपाययोजनेअंतर्गत गेल्या वर्षी (2015) कराश्रय सुविधा देणाऱ्या देशांमध्ये अघोषित मालमत्ता असलेल्यांना माहिती सरकारकडे उघड करण्याचा आदेश देण्यात आला होता. "त्यावेळी बऱ्याच जणांनी सरकारने '
scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1'], use_stemmer=True)
scores = scorer.score(t1,t2)
print(scores)
```

O/P:

> {'rouge1': Score(precision=1.0, recall=0.25, fmeasure=0.4)}

**This is working.**

**Case 3:**

```
t1='नवी दिल्ली: जगभरातील उद्योजक, सत्ताधीशांच्या काळ्या पैशासंदर्भातील उघड झालेला गोपनीय दस्ताऐवज ‘पनामा पेपर्स‘मुळे खळबळ माजलेली असताना, परदेशात मालमत्ता लपवणाऱ्या भारतीयांना ही कृती महागात पडू शकते असा कडक इशारा केंद्रीय अर्थमंत्री अरुण जेटली यांनी दिला आहे. काळ्या पैशाच्या '
t2='नवी दिल्ली: जगभरातील उद्योजक, सत्ताधीशांच्या काळ्या पैशासंदर्भातील उघड झालेला गोपनीय दस्ताऐवज ‘पनामा पेपर्स‘मुळे खळबळ माजलेली असताना, परदेशात मालमत्ता लपवणाऱ्या भारतीयांना ही कृती महागात पडू शकते असा कडक इशारा केंद्रीय अर्थमंत्री अरुण जेटली यांनी दिला आहे. तरीही परदेशात '
scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1'], use_stemmer=True)
scores = scorer.score(t1,t2)
print(scores)
```

O/P:

> {'rouge1': Score(precision=0.0, recall=0.0, fmeasure=0.0)}

**Why it is not working in this case, although there are overlapping words between the two sentences?**

I tried it for English language, it works. Even it is working for non-english/marathi one, but not all.

Comment: I'm just curious, is there a specific reason to use `rouge1` over `rougeL`?

Comment: Actually All ROUGE values are giving the same result. I just tried ROUGE1 to simplify it to debug the code. ROUGE1 being the basic one to at least work with single words.